# Import .SQL Containing COPY Statements Into PSQL

Tags: postgresql, sqlite

Is there a way to import a .sql that contains COPY statements instead of INSERT statements into an sqlite3 db?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly. Even if there were, it'd likely have other PostgreSQL-specific syntax.

Load it into PostgreSQL then use the `psql` command `\copy`  to export CSV from each table.

Alternately, do a `--data-only --column-inserts` dump with `pg_dump`, which will produce a script that's somewhat more SQLite compatible, though it'll likely still require some changes (sed/awk/perl etc) to load.